# Как в боте телеграмм написать input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как в боте телеграмм сделать input.
В питоне метод input ждёт ввода пользователя, а в telebot такого нет, при нажатии кнопки к примеру ввести число, если на нажатие этой кнопки был написан код и ещё к примеру функция с `print('Тук-тук! Кто там??')` код кнопки и код функции выполнится сразу же, человек даже не сможет ввести число или текст.

Есть способ решить эту проблему? Буду очень рад любым ответам и предложениям!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","Hello"])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'привет, введи любой текст и отправь')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'на предыдущем шаге вы ввели\n{}'.format(message.text))
```

[register_next_step_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)